# Embed youtube video without making extra HTTP request and increasing page size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, youtube-javascript-api

I run a blog which talks about music. It's a custom Php based CMS and each blogpost has a minimum of 2 videos in it. Now, these youtube videos extra HTTP request and increase page size by 2MB. This is really a concern for me as I'm losing out on google search ranking due to page size and performance issue. I found a way of doing it via this tutorial

[(https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/).](https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/)

I have implemented this solution for blogs that I'll be posting from tomorrow but need a solution for blogs that were posted before. Those blogs had youtube embeds via iframe and I do not know how to create a solution for them.

My guess would be to use jquery append & remove? If yes, can someone assist me how do I proceed? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: google search ranking is not the king of the internet, content is, you blindly follow numbers, 2mb is not a big number and what has this got to do with fewer http request?

Comment: I respect your opinion but when the page size increases to 4.7MB and HTTP request to 115, I have to take note of this. Content is the king, but in my demography, people run 3G and on mobile page size matters a lot. Here's a screenshot for your reference - https://ibb.co/bCL53Q

Comment: you need to minify css and js first man, you may have a problem with the youtube script, it should load only once not multiple times

Comment: Yes, @madalinivascu I have lighthouse and page speed insight telling me that. I will fix those by today. Can you advise why base.js is loading multiple times?

Comment: most likely the you have a loop in there that triggers the same script for each video

Comment: there's no loop. The entire blog description that has those 4 videos are fetched from mysql and rendered onto the page. If there'd have been a loop I would have known.